# How to remove blank lines in .txt files

Tags: windows, script, shell-script, text-editing

I want to change a text file's format, removing all blank lines. How can I do that?

---

> (2) 5.    The function of the condenser is to:
>
> a)   vapourise the liquid refrigerant
>
> b)   change high pressure refrigerant vapour to liquid
>
> c)   pressurise low pressure refrigerant vapour
>
> d)   vent off vapourised refrigerant
>
> e)   lower the liquid refrigerant pressure
>
> (2) 6.    One tonne of refrigeration is:
>
> a)   13958 kJ per day
>
> b)   100 kJ per minute
>
> c)   233 kJ per minute
>
> d)   13958 J per hour
>
> e)   335 J per second

---

> (2) 5. The function of the condenser is to:
>   a)   vapourise the
>   liquid refrigerant
>   b)    change high pressure refrigerant vapour to
>   liquid
>   c)    pressurise low pressure refrigerant vapour
>   d)  vent
>   off vapourised refrigerant
>   e)    lower the liquid refrigerant
>   pressure
>
> (2) 6.    One tonne of refrigeration is:
>   a)  13958 kJ per day
>  
>   b)    100 kJ per minute
>   c)   233 kJ per minute
>   d)   13958 J per
>   hour
>   e)  335 J per second

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use GNU sed:

```
sed -i -e "/^$/d" su.txt
```

Will delete blank lines.

---

If you're on a BSD variant or OS X, use this instead:

```
sed -i '' -e "/^$/d" su.txt
```

Here, `-i` takes an *extension* as an argument – using the GNU sed syntax would result in a file `su.txt-e` being created.

Comment: Hello ,thanks for help,. I installed GNU sed in Window vista , tried SED itself  not working, no SED window up

Comment: @Brant What do you mean by "not working" and "no SED window up"? Can you run the command from a prompt? If not, what errors do you see?

Comment: First I could not find SED shortcut anywhere on startup  menu or desktop.  Then I run the bin in Program Files--> GnuWin32-->bin-->SED under C drive. Then Black window up for a split of second and dissappeared

Comment: @Brant it's a command line tool. That command will edit it in-place, invoked from a shell. There is no GUI. I recommend you install cygwin on Windows and use the one that comes with it.

Comment: Installing cygwin just to remove some lines from a text file seems a bit overkill to me.

Comment: Thank you Keith.  After I installed cygwin , the SED command work in the GUI window,   now I can change the text format, this will save

Comment: Thank you Keith.  After I installed cygwin , the SED command work in the GUI window,   now I can change the text format, this will save time when many files need to convert. The format displayed correctly in Wordpad but not in Notepad, anyway I already get what I need...thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by using grep:

```
grep . file
```

Or try the [ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor))-way (cross-platform compatible):

```
ex -s +'v/\S/d' -cwq test.txt
```

For multiple files (edit in-place):

```
ex -s +'bufdo!v/\S/d' -cxa *.txt
```

<sup>Note: The `:bufdo` command is not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).</sup>

Without modifying the file (just print on the standard output):

```
cat test.txt | ex -s +'v/\S/d' +%p +q! /dev/stdin
```

Comment: note bufdo is not POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html