# Using sed, how can I delete all blank lines?

Tags: linux, sed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove blank lines in .txt files](https://superuser.com/questions/440930/how-to-remove-blank-lines-in-txt-files)

Using sed, how can I delete all blank lines?

Input file:

Steve Blenheim:238-923-7366:95 Latham Lane, Easton, PA 83755:11/12/56:20300

Betty Boop:245-836-8357:635 Cutesy Lane, Hollywood, CA 91464:6/23/23:14500

Igor Chevsky:385-375-8395:3567 Populus Place, Caldwell, NJ 23875:6/18/68:23400

Norma Corder:397-857-2735:74 Pine Street, Dearborn, MI 23874:3/28/45:245500

Jennifer Cowan:548-834-2348:583 Laurel Ave., Kingsville, TX 83745:10/1/35:58900

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing empty lines from *input-file* with *sed* can be done like this:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' input-file
```

The **-i** switch tells sed to do its modifications directly *in place* (without creating a new file), **^** is the symbol for the *beginning of the line*, **$** is the symbol for the *end of the line* and **d** activates the *delete action*.

Thus, the command above says *Match all lines in input-file with nothing between the beginning and the end of the line and delete them from the file directly.*